# Build error with pod in Unit Test target

Tags: ios, cocoapods, google-cast

My Xcode project is failing to build the Unit Test target. It complains of undefined symbol link errors for the Google Cast iOS SDK. I'm looking for ways to figure out what this error is and how to fix it.

Some relevant information so far:

• My application target builds and runs fine with this pod.

• This pod 'google-cast-sdk' is a pod shared between both my application and Unit Test target.

• Unit Test target compiles but can't link.

• Link errors are of the form:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GCKUIStyle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UMChromecastMoviePlayerView.o

• Pretty much every symbol that I use from the SDK shows up as undefined.

• I get similar errors when building for both the Simulator and a device.

• I haven't done anything else to my project to use this pod other than adding it to my podfile.

• Out of 23 pods in the podfile, this is the only one that gives an error.

I'm looking for any ideas on how to troubleshoot this build error.

Thanks in advance.

Doug

Comment: Can you post the relevant piece of your podfile? May be that it is not included in the test target there.

Comment: It is in the shared_pods section.

Comment: workspace 'udemy.xcworkspace'

platform :ios, '9.0'

# ignore all warnings from all pods

def shared_pods
    pod 'google-cast-sdk'
end

target 'udemy-mobile-ios' do
    use_frameworks!
    shared_pods
end

target 'unit-tests' do
    use_frameworks!
    inherit! :search_paths
    shared_pods
    pod 'OCMock', '~> 3.4.1'
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs', '~> 6.1.0'
end

Comment: Thanks, next question would be is the test target in your project given the same name as what you have in the Podfile (unit-tests)?

Comment: Yes, the target names match between podfile and Xcode project.